# PHP JAVASCRIPT parameters passing

Tags: javascript, php, parameters, parameter-passing

I have a code like this in php page

```
<?php
$a = 1;
<script>
var foo<?php echo $a?> //Var foo1 will be created
</script>
?>
```

but then i want to separate the javascipt page and pass a parameter

```
<?php
 // some scripts here...

<script src="initialize.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        initialize(<?php echo $a?>);
    });
</script>
```

javascript page / initialize.js

```
initialize(a){  var foo+a } // i also wanted to create a var foo1
```

But console will error cannot initialize foo+a variable

what i want to attain is create a javascript var foo1 from this

Thank you

Comment: Why would you want to use php to create javascript variable names? That doesn't make any sense and makes it very hard to debug your code.

Comment: Dynamically generated global names are also a terrible idea.

Comment: Please give a more concrete (and complete) example of what you're trying to achieve. It's rather likely that there's a conceptual flaw. Are you certain about what `function() { var x1 }` does ...and what it doesn't do? For this to make any sense you'd need an understanding of javascript's objects and activation contexts deeper than your question suggests.

Comment: i have edited the question hope it is now clearer

Comment: `hope it is now clearer` not really ;-)  Let's assume the syntax were correct: What effect exatly do you expect from calling initialize(something)?  (And please assume that "the variable gets initialized" is not a sufficient answer ;-))

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $a = 1;
    echo "<script> var foo".$a.";</script>"
?>
```

or inside your HTML

```
<?php $a = 1; ?>
<script>
var foo<?php echo $a?>;
</script>
```

Comment: OP was trying to add HTML to a page without echo'ing them, if he removes the surrouning PHP tags of the whole snippet he posted it'll also be fixed. op also forgot `;` after the line.

Comment: Actually my goal was to initialize the variable through PASSING the php parameter because i wanted to separate the javascript from the php/html page. sorry if the question wasnt clear

Comment: I'm sorry your question still isn't clear, you've posted a broken snippet of code that wasn't going to work nonetheless, and my answer fixes the code you posted and does what looks like your code was trying to accomplish.